# Vectorized approach to comparing consecutive columns in a dataframe and then updating a column in that dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a large dataframe with with named objects that can be grouped by an event ID. Each group consists of one or more events. The event detection mechanism often starts a new group before the current series completes, resulting in a lot of short events where there really should be a smaller number of longer events.

I can identify groups that belong together by the time interval between events - if the last event in one group is within N seconds of the first event in the next group then the groups should be joined.

In pseudocode, I want to:

```
for all rows in dataframe:
    if row['time_interval'] is less than N
    and if row['ID'] is not equal to next_row['ID']
    then where row['ID'] is the first row's value set it to the second row's value
```

My data looks like this:

| TimeUTC | Name | ID | time_interval_seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01 08:58:47+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 9c3807ce-bf21-4cd8-b4ac-f2da440340dc |  |
| 2021-06-01 09:00:11+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 16e9ea6c-2722-4881-bd35-5867e83be19b | 4 |
| 2021-06-01 09:00:21+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 16e9ea6c-2722-4881-bd35-5867e83be19b | 10 |
| 2021-06-01 09:00:24+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 16e9ea6c-2722-4881-bd35-5867e83be19b | 3 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 2021-06-01 09:04:25+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 204fb08c-7271-4399-b111-81488f5f26ec | 152 |
| 2021-06-01 09:04:35+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 204fb08c-7271-4399-b111-81488f5f26ec | 10 |
| 2021-06-01 09:05:23+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 204fb08c-7271-4399-b111-81488f5f26ec | 48 |
| 2021-06-01 09:06:30+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 4bfedd19-b081-467a-8441-bebaef05520c | 6 |
| 2021-06-01 09:07:04+00:00 | 0M63HB200SY101 | 4bfedd19-b081-467a-8441-bebaef05520c | 34 |

Since the time_interval on the second row is < N and the ID's are different, then the first row's ID would become 16e9ea6c-2722-4881-bd35-5867e83be19b.

Even though the ID's change between rows 4 and 5 we will not update the ID since the time_interval is > N.

However, all of the IDs in the second block will change to the ID's from the third block.

It feels like I can detect the change with this lambda function:

```
    if r2.time_interval_seconds < 5:
        if r1['ID'] != r2['ID']:
            return(r2['ID'])

   df['newID'] = df[df.apply(lambda x: row_compare(x, x's iloc+1)
```

But a) I cannot figure out how to pass in both rows (.shift()?) and b) access the original dataframe to update it.

If, for a given row, I could pass the original dataframe into the lambda function then I could join the two groups within the function.

I have millions of these rows and iterating over them really isn't an option though that would be straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it without apply, but still with vectorized calculation:

I assume that the `df` is sorted by `TimeUTC`.
You create a new column `newID` with only the value for start of each group. A group starts when `time_interval_seconds >= N`

```
df['newID'] = np.where(
                  time_interval_seconds >= N,
                  df['ID'], np.nan
              )
```

You initialize the first value of the column :

```
df['newID'].iloc[0] = df['ID'].iloc[0]
```

And then you forward fill it to complete the column

```
df['newId'] = df['newId'].ffill()
```

Comment: It is a little bit unclear in your description, here, I forward fill the column, in your example, you say that you want to update the first row with the value of the second row, so you can adapt the logic and back fill the data as well.

Comment: I see how this works and think it should do the trick. I'll go take it for a spin. Thank you.